# Why second example compiles sucessfuly

Tags: java, generics

```
import java.util.*;    

class Test
{
    public static class Base
    {           
    }

    public static class Derived1
        extends Base
    {               
    }

    public static class Derived2
        extends Base
    {               
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //Example1.
        List<? extends Base> e = new ArrayList<Base>();
        e.add(new Derived1()); //this won't compile

        //Example2.
        List<? super Base> b = new ArrayList<Base>();
        b.add(new Derived1()); //this compiles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<? super Base> b` can be assigned either a `List<Base>` or a `List<Object>`. A `Derived1` instance can be added to both, so the `b.add(new Derived1())` statement passes compilation.

On the other hand, `List<? extends Base> e` may be assigned a `List<Derived2>`, so the compiler doesn't allow to add a `Derived1` instance to it.

Answer (score 1):

See [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

If you are adding something to a `List<T>`, then the list is a *consumer* of the thing you are adding. As such, the type of the list elements, `T`, must be the same as the thing you are trying to add *or a supertype*.

Comment: ty. for this answer.:)